# Recode values in HIVE based on numeric condition

Tags: sql, hive, recode

I am trying to recode a column with numeric values where 99 and 199 are represent missing values. I would like to recode that to be missing as (.) so having no value when the condition applies, keeping all other values as they are entered. For example,

if test =99 or test=199 then . else = populate with the other values.

How can I can I do that in HIVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense.  `99` and `199` are *numbers*, but `.` is not.  So, I would recommend `NULL`:

```
(case when test not in (99, 199) then test end) as test_recoded
```

If `test` is really a string, then you can use the above or alternatively:

```
(case when test not in ('99', '199') then test else '.' end) as test_recoded
```